# Search for Woocommerce Products in Specific Category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Any idea why this search is excluding all other categories correctly: http://botanicaevents.com/rentals/?s=white&product_cat=rentals

While this search is NOT, it is still including the other category: http://botanicaevents.com/rentals/?s=white&product_cat=floral

The second link above should only include the test product "White Floral Product Test"

Comment: On your dev install, does it work correctly on the default themes? Does it work without any plugins other than WooCommerce? Can you share the corresponding SQL queries and the skeleton of the product_cat category tree?