# Show products in specific category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm a newbie in WordPress and Woocommerce. Now I've visit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476081/search-for-woocommerce-products-in-specific-category), but have no answer or 0 answer also.

So I've asked this question.

> How I can show only one category in my homepage ?

and this question:

> Where the post loop exist?

Comment: Your first question depends on how your theme is structured, but in general your best best is [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). Read more about the [loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). The loop is generally in your theme, though WooCommerce's product archives templates are in the WooCommerce plugin.

Comment: This appears to be a signpost to other questions, and not a question in itself. Since you have an answer below, I suggest you change the question body to what you would have asked to result in the answer you have given - as it stands it will close as off-topic.

Comment: (Please, under no circumstances should you add deadline begging to your questions. We are really, really tired of it. You are addressing volunteers, not employees).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after a very long way of search, i found the easiest way to do that, and i will make it with u step by step:

---

**STEP 1**
go to your dashboard and click on all pages on pages menu
**Pages** -> **All Pages**

[image: Click on All pages on pages menu]

---

**STEP 2**
open your shop page to edit it in mycase it is:

[image: Open your shop page to edit]

---

**STEP 3** open the text mode of your page:
[image]

---

**STEP 4** add this shortcode to your text body:

[product_category category="YOUR_CATAGORY_SLUG"] in my case [product_category category="بطاقات-itunes-gift-card"]

[image]

---

**Finally** Press Update

[image]